# inductive step of proof by structural induction

Tags: haskell

I am given the following 2 versions of a tree-flattening program and i am asked to prove identical behaviour.

```
flatten::Tree->[Int]
flatten (Leaf z)        =[z]                             F.1
flatten (Node x y)      =concat (flatten x)(flatten y)   F.2

flatten'::Tree->Int->[Int]
flatten' (Leaf z) a     =concat [z] a                    P.1
flatten' (Node x y) a   =flatten' x (flatten' y a)       P.2

concat->[a]->a->[a]
concat [] a             =a                               C.1
concat (h:t) a          =h:concat t a                    C.2
```

Prove that:

```
flatten' z a = concat (flatten z) a
```

Base Case:

```
LHS:
    flatten' (Leaf z) a = concat [z] a                   By P.1
RHS:
    concat (flatten z) a = concat (flatten (Leaf z)) a
                         = concat [z] a                  By F.1 and C.1

LHS=RHS, hence base case holds
```

Inductive Case:

> (Only possible thanks to the guy below who explained how induction on
>   binary trees works!)

```
Assume that:
   flatten' x a = concat (flatten x) a                   Ind. Hyp1
   flatten' y a = concat (flatten y) a                   Ind. Hyp2

Show that:
   flatten'(Node x y) a = concat (flatten (Node x y)) a

LHS:
   flatten' (Node x y) a = 
   flatten' x (flatten' y a)                             By P.2
   flatten' x (concat (flatten y) a)                     By Ind. Hyp2
   concat (flatten x) (concat (flatten y) a)             By Ind. Hyp1

RHS:
   concat (flatten (Node x y)) a =
   concat (concat (flatten x) (flatten y)) a             By F.2
   concat (flatten x) (concat (flatten y) a)             By C.2

   LHS = RHS, hence inductive step holds. End of proof.
```

Comment: Using a proof assistant would make your life much easier. [Here is the proof in agda.](https://gist.github.com/yuriy0/6be284048182000d8753)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When inducting on lists, your induction hypothesis is that the wanted property holds on the list tail, and you have to prove that it also holds on the whole list.

On trees, it's only slightly different: your induction hypothesis is that the wanted property holds on *both* subtrees, and you have to prove that is also holds on the whole tree.

```
Assume that:
   forall a, flatten' x a = concat (flatten x) a         Ind. Hyp. 1
   forall a, flatten' y a = concat (flatten y) a         Ind. Hyp. 2

Show that:
   forall a, flatten'(Node x y) a = concat (flatten (Node x y)) a
```

I think you can now guess how to proceed from here, so I won't spoil the fun. You might need to rely on some basic property of `concat` for some sub-step.

Final note: in your base case, you mentioned `C.1` as a justification -- are you sure you actually used that?

Comment: The induction hypothesis doesn't necessarily have to use `a` uniformly. Interestingly enough, this is much easier to prove if you take the induction hypotheses `flatten' x (flatten' y a) = concat (flatten x) (flatten' y a)`.

Comment: @chi: Thanks for explaining the inductive hypotheses on binary trees.

Comment: @user2407038 That's right - I now quantify `a` universally so that it doesn't have to be uniform.